# SOAP Request over https fails everytime

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, timeout

my first time doing a SOAP Request fails and fails again.
I have to send some Data via SOAP but i dont get a stable connection.

I use the SOAP Extension of PHP. My Code looks like the following.

```
$certificate = file_get_contents(DATA_PATH.'/modules/va/misc/CKTC.cer');
$options = array(
                'uri'               => 'https://data2.kroschke.net/service/MeinAutoUeberfuehrungen',
                'allow_self_signed' => true,
                'verify_peer'       => true,
                'local_cert'        => $certificate,
                'trace'             => 1,
                'exceptions'        => true,
            );
$wsdl = 'https://data2.kroschke.net/service/MeinAutoUeberfuehrungen?WSDL';

$SOAPClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);

fb($SOAPClient->__getFunctions());
```

Now my Problem is, that the SOAP Request always runs into a timeout.

I checked my php settings and SOAP and OpenSSL are activated.

I also tried it with a .pem instead of a .cer File. Same Problem.

This is what i get all the time:
***Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(https://data2.kroschke.net/service/MeinAutoUeberfuehrungen?WSDL): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in***

Anyone who can help?

PS: Dont mind the fb() Function. Just a function to print everything into FireBug.

Comment: Well, i just tried the url in your post on my browser, and the server is not responding. Is it the server is down?

Comment: Did you made the SOAP Server? Ya @iWantSimpleLife same here... I think the server is down..

Comment: I can reach it. But i have to accept the Certificate.

Comment: But the side did not even prompt for a cert. ARe you using the correct cert for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try to open https://data2.kroschke.net or https://data2.kroschke.net/service/MeinAutoUeberfuehrungen?WSDL in you browser: you'll get a timeout, too.

the best solution would be to get in contact with the provider of that soap-server ([kroschke.com](http://www.kroschke.com)/[kroschke.de](http://www.kroschke.de/) ?) and ask them why their server is down or seems to hang.

**EDIT:**
this doesn't seem to be the problem, so your only option is to set the timeout to a higher value. for this, just add `connection_timeout` (value in seconds) to your options:

```
$options = array(
            'uri'               => 'https://data2.kroschke.net/service/MeinAutoUeberfuehrungen',
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
            'verify_peer'       => true,
            'local_cert'        => $certificate,
            'trace'             => 1,
            'exceptions'        => true,
            'connection_timeout'=> 30
        );
```

if it still times out, set the value even higher - if it still times out then, try to test the soap-communication with a program like [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) before implementing it with PHP - if you get problems with soapUI, too, contact the provider of that soap-server and ask why their methods take such a long time.

for more information, take a look at the [soapclient and it's options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php).

Comment: For me the server is available. I can get the WSDL without any problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I contacted the Admin of the Web Service and wait for an answer. They will give me a code snippet that works.